# Drupal Multi Site Folder structure

Tags: multi-sites

I have a simple question.

I am trying to create a folder inside the Drupal installation that will not be shared to all the multi-sites.

For example:

> www.mydomain.com/xxx
>
> www.anotherdomain.com/xxx

I need this two folders of *xxx* should go to different path.

How can I achieve that?

I tried to create a new folder in Drupal root folder, but like this all the domains familiar with the same contents.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend @Pierre.Vriens answer , you could then add a rewrite rule to make the urls a bit nicer

assumptions

1. you've got public files set up
2. you've got a url 'normalisation' (either symlinks in files directory or 301s)

   `RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/files/$1 [L]`

in your host will take

```
http://www.example.com/filename.pdf
```

and rewrite it to

```
http://www.example.com/sites/www.example.com/files/filename.pdf
```

what do i mean by url normalisation ?
well, if you can get example.com - then you'll get a 404 - as the folder in the sites directory is www.example.com

an easy solution is to use symlinks in the sites directory, or to use 301 redirects

to use symlinks, assume you have

```
sites/www.example.com
```

you could then create a symlink to it as follows

```
ln -s www.example.com example.com
```

this would create a symbolic link from

```
sites/example.com
```

to the www.example.com folder. this means that both www.example.com, and example.com would be found when the rewrite rule runs

Comment: what do you mean by using symlinks as an easy solution can you please show an example for this?

Comment: sure - I've just added that to the answer

Comment: Thanks solved the problem .
Did it with virtual Dirctory ( Running on iis ) 
virtual directory was pointing to the sites/mydomain per iis configure.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create such folder in the Drupal root folder. But instead create an `xxx` subfolder in both of these subdirs:

- `sites/mydomain` (assuming `mydomain` is what maps to your `www.mydomain.com`).
- `sites/anotherdomain` (assuming `anotherdomain` is what maps to your `www.anotherdomain.com`).

By doing so, the 2 folders `sites/mydomain/xxx` and `sites/anotherdomain/xxx` for sure will not be shared between those 2 sites within a multi-site construction.