# How to create sub-directory based multi-site?

Tags: 7, multi-sites, subsites

I want to create subdirectory based multisite, for this I roamed full day in internet but nowhere I found how can do the symlink in a proper manner. I will divide my requirement below:

Site name I have is: capacad(accesible by url: `localhost:81/capacad/`)

I want multisite url should be: `localhost:81/capacad/subsite`

So to achieve this I created a folder named subsite in `C:\xampp\htdocs\capacad\sites\subsite`.

Later this step I have to do symlink. So how can I achieve that.

I tried this command: `C:\>mklink /d C:\xampp\htdocs\capacad\sites\subsite C:\xampp\htdocs\capacad`

This is creating multiple loops inside the subsite folder.

I am not getting the what path names where to link. Can anybody please explain me elaborately how can I achieve this in windows.

Thanks for any suggestions.

I followed some below links:

[link1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171768/drupal-multi-site-folder-structure)

[link2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-Links)

[link3](https://docs.acquia.com/articles/adding-flexibility-your-server-structure-using-symlinks)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the site names in the file sites/site.php

```
$sites = array(
  'site1.your-multisite.local' => 'website1',
  'your-multisite.local.site2' => 'website2',
);
```

Also update the settings.php file of each subdomain with the credentials of respective sites.

Also need to update the site url from the host settings.

```
 ServerAlias    *.your-multisite.local your-multisite.local.*
```